# Libertine OpenType

Tags: libertine

I am using the Libertine font family in a document as follows:

```
\RequirePackage[ttscale=.875,oldstyle]{libertine}
\renewcommand*\libertine@figurestyle{LF}
\RequirePackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\renewcommand*\libertine@figurestyle{OsF}
\input glyphtounicode
\pdfgentounicode=1
```

The document is compiled via the pdflatex engine and I need to open in a graphic tool like Inskcape. Upon opening, I get the following error message:

> The font LinBiolinumT is missing. The font LinBiolinumTB is missing. The font LinLibertineT is missing. The font LinLibertineTB is missing. The font txexs is missing.

I've investigated a bit and see that the OpenType version of Libertine is available on CTAN: http://mirror.neu.edu.cn/CTAN/fonts/libertine/opentype/. However, it looks like the above requested families are not available in the OpenType format. I also see that the latter are listed here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine/tfm

Is it possible to convert them to OpenType?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Libertinus` instead. It is the Libertine with corrected glyphs and math:

```
 \documentclass{...}
 \usepackage{libertinus-otf}
 ...
```

Comment: I should compile with lualatex then? I'm using pdflatex.

Comment: with `pdflatex` use `usepackage{libertinus}`. But then you do not have the OpenType Variant.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't told us how you created your document or which fonts it uses.  The T fonts are type 1, not opentype.  Compile the document using xelatex or lualatex to embed the opentype versions.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I edited my post.

Comment: libertine or libertinus: use xelatex or lualatex to get opentype fonts